# Updated list of the most used and reliable quantitative tests in Psychology

Tags: measurement, test

I studied Psychology some years ago and ended up as a programmer. Now, I'm working on a personal side project to build an API to serve correction for different psychology tests.

Since I moved out of the field for so many years, I'm having a hard time finding quantitative instruments to evaluate different aspects of the human psychology: personality, resilience, control locus etc...

All the tests must be reliable (they are precise and achieve to measure what they want to, backed up by studies), up-to-date and frequently used among professionals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question may be too broad for this forum.  Maybe if there is a reasonable way to set objective criteria for "reliable", "up to date", and "frequently used", then the question can be acceptable here, but as-is, it is too open to interpretation, and would require an answer that is far too long.

Answer (score 1):

The [International Personality Item Pool](https://ipip.ori.org/) would be a great place to start.

Comment: IPIP is a great project but I doubt that it is used the most. For instance, the IPIP-NEO-120 was cited 359 times, the NEO-PI-R about 38k times (google scholar).